# Test a callback Function using jest and enzyme in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tdd, jestjs, enzyme

I am new to TDD and I want to test my callback function in my Age component :
my **Age.js** file is following :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import actions from "../../actions";
import TextFieldComponent from "../Module/TextFieldComponent";

export class Age extends Component {

  ageValueCallBack = age => {
    console.log("value is : ", age);
    this.props.selectAgeAction(age)
  };

  render() {
    const props = {
      onChange: this.ageValueCallBack,
      hintText : 'Eg. 25',
      floatingLabelText: "Age(Years)",
      value : (this.props.usersData) ? this.props.usersData.basic.age : null
    };
    return <TextFieldComponent {...props} />;
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ usersData }) {
  return {
    usersData
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  selectAgeAction: actions.selectAgeValue
})(Age);
```

where my **TextFieldComponent** is following :

```
import TextField from "material-ui/TextField";

const TextFieldComponent = props => {
  return (
    <TextField
        onChange={(event, string) => {
        props.onChange(string)
      }}
      floatingLabelText={props.floatingLabelText || "floatingLabelText"}
      value={props.value || null}
      hintText={props.hintText || "hintText will be here"}
      autoFocus ={true || props.autoFocus}
    />
  );
};
```

I want to test **ageValueCallBack** function of Age component but I'm not getting any particular method to reach there.

Any insight will be helpful.

Thanks..

Comment: What you have to do is that you need a spy, sinonJs is good for that job.
 So when you render Age component, prop selectAgeAction="the sinon spy".
Also you need to make an onChangeEvent on your TextField, and then assert against the sinon spy. 
http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.0.1/spies/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With enzyme you can trigger the `onChange` event on the `TextFieldComponent` using [`simulate('change', {}, 'someString')`](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/simulate.html). The `selectAgeAction` in your `Age.js` needs to be a spy created with `jest.fn()`:

```
const selectAgeAction = jest.fn()
const component = shallow(<Age selectAgeAction={selectAgeAction} />)
component.find('TextField').simulate('change', {}, '10')
expect(selectAgeAction).toHaveBeenCalledWith('10')
```

Comment: This is really useful, what is the second argument of `simulate()` which you set to `{}`?

Comment: This would be the event argument the callback is called with, usually something like `{target: value: 'someValue'}`